# Seeking ModelBuilder tool for changing Feature Class source?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, modelbuilder, feature-class

I'm trying to add a tool that will give me the opportunity to change the source of a feature within my model.  So this is what I figured out until this point.

I have a feature called: Pipelines
-   I make a selection were Type = “Gas Low Pressure” (for example) 
-   from this selection there will be add a Feature layer (an otherwise it will not accept the symbology layer tool) 
-   And with the given symbology  there will be layers add to the mxd.

But now I have several new features and I want to replace the source of all those features back to the original source (featureclass) “pipeline”.

I cannot find standard tools as a solution within ArcMap.

Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As i understand your question correctly, you could add your origin feature as a parameter again and set a precondition to the previous processes.

To set a precondition you use the blue-green-connected button and set Vorbedingung/Precondition with right-click.

[image]
[image]